# select top 1 record with two grouping keys

Tags: sql-server

id date value

```
1001 2015-06-01 A
1001 2015-06-30 B
1001 2015-07-10 C
1001 2015-07-11 D
1001 2015-08-01 E
1001 2015-08-15 F
1001 2015-08-20 G
```

Desired output will be

```
1001 2015-06-30 6 B
1001 2015-07-11 7 D
1001 2015-08-20 8 G
```

I would like to subset one observation only for each month for each id.

e.g. I have three records for id 1001 in July ('2015-07-01', '2015-07-10', '2015-07-20'). Therefore I just need '2015-07-20' record only. similar for other month.

```
SELECT
 s.id,
 s.value,
 max(s.date) as [MaxDate],
 month(s.date) as [DateMonth]
FROM
 name s
WHERE
 s.date between '2015-06-01' and '2015-09-01'
GROUP BY
 s.id, month(s.date)
```

With error message

> Is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

It seems there is problem when I am using the function `Month()`

Comment: which database you are using? SQL? which version?

Comment: Sample data with expected Output will help

Comment: `s.value` should be added in `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select 
  res.id,
  res.date,
  month(res.date) as [DateMonth],
  res.value 
from name res
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT
    s.id,
    max(s.date) as [MaxDate],
    month(s.date) as [DateMonth]
  FROM
    name s
  WHERE
    s.date between '2015-06-01' and '2015-09-01'
  GROUP BY
    s.id, month(s.date)) a 
ON a.id = res.id AND a.MaxDate = res.date
```

Comment: The subquery after the `INNER JOIN` and before `ON` is the one which does all the **filtering and grouping**. so any WHERE clause will have to be placed along with the current where clause. But **ordering** will have to be done on the final dataset, so `ORDER BY` should be added to the end after `GROUP BY`

Comment: @useR what do you mean by close? did it not give you desired results?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with the **Month** function. Its with the value column. Use value in GROUP BY clause too.

If you really need the value column without GROUP BY, use a CTE first get the max in the select with ID and month. Then Join on ID and MONTH with Name Table to get the value.

Something like this:

```
    ;WITH   DateCTE AS     
(SELECT   s.id,
                 max(s.date) AS [MaxDate],
                 month(s.date) AS [DateMonth]
        FROM     name AS s
        WHERE    s.date BETWEEN '2015-06-01' AND '2015-09-01'
        GROUP BY s.id, month(s.date))
SELECT s.id,
       K.value,
       [MaxDate],
       [DateMonth]
FROM   DateCTE AS S
       INNER JOIN
       name AS K
       ON s.id = K.ID
          AND [MaxDate] = K.date;
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: Hi i got thte following error Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Line 1: Incorrect syntax near ';'.

Comment: Can you try this again. Check it in a new Window. It should work

Comment: Did you execute the query in a new window once??... I'm able to execute it successfully on my machine..

Answer (score 1):

If your version of Sql Server supports the `row_number` function, you can try this:

```
declare @a table (
    id int not null,
    dt datetime not null,
    val varchar(10) not null
)

insert into @a values (1001, '2015-06-01', 'A')
insert into @a values (1001, '2015-06-30', 'B')
insert into @a values (1001, '2015-07-10', 'C')
insert into @a values (1001, '2015-07-11', 'D')
insert into @a values (1001, '2015-08-01', 'E')
insert into @a values (1001, '2015-08-15', 'F')
insert into @a values (1001, '2015-08-20', 'G')
insert into @a values (1001, '2015-08-20', 'H')
insert into @a values (1002, '2015-08-20', 'I')
insert into @a values (1002, '2015-08-20', 'J')

select sub.id, sub.dt, sub.val, month(sub.dt) as [month]
from (
    select id, dt, val, row_number() over (partition by id, month(dt) order by dt desc, val) as rn from @a
) as sub
where sub.rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are receiving because you have not added `s.value` in your `Group by` clause.

Comment: for same month, it will have two records for one id for each s.value.